# My If statement isn't returning a value based on cell being blank or has data

Tags: google-apps-script

My If statement says that if the cell it is looking at is null, then return x, if it's got a value in it, then Y... The logger shows data in the cell, but it still returns x!

I've tried changing to isblank, is null, is "". I can see that it is logging data, but it is still returning the answer for a blank cell

```
function trackingSheetUpdate() {

  var now = new Date();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Active Campaign');

  var Tracking = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking')

  var getUpdate = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 5).getValue();

  var dateResult = now - sourceSheet.getRange(2, 6).getValue();

  var openSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(getUpdate).getSheetByName('Sheet1')

  var weeklyUpdate = openSS.getRange(2, 1).getValue();

  if (dateResult > 1 && dateResult <= 7); {

    if (weeklyUpdate == null, Tracking.getRange(2, 2).setValue("x"));

    else

      ("Y");
  }
}
```

I want x if the cell is blank and Y if cell is not blank, but it only returns x! Eventually I am going to loop this through a dynamic range, but want to get the basics right first!

Comment: Your code seems to contain syntax errors. Please [edit] your question to fix those, and then [beautify](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=beautify+javascript&ia=answer) it.

Comment: I've edited and beautified it.. Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created some test sheet data of my own and the below code seemed to work as you're expecting it to.

```
function trackingSheetUpdate() {
  var now = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Active Campaign');
  var trackSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tracking');
  var getUpdate = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 5).getValue();
  var dateResult = now - sourceSheet.getRange(2, 6).getValue();
  var openSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(getUpdate).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var weeklyUpdate = openSheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();

  if (dateResult > 1 && dateResult <= 7); {
    if (weeklyUpdate == '') {
      trackSheet.getRange(2, 2).setValue("x");
    } else {
      trackSheet.getRange(2, 2).setValue("y");
    }
  }
}
```

Of course this relies on your sheet data being correct, for example you need `var getUpdate` to be a URL. I have also renamed some variables for consistency with the rest of the script, along with some grammatical changes like making sure there are semicolons to end lines etc.